# Windows update/fix ad while using TOR on youtube

Tags: security

I was using TOR yesterday (July 21, 2019) and received one of those ads right over the music video I was watching on youtube. This ad definitely looked like a scam - it would probably have downloaded a malicious program had I clicked on the ad. The ad said "Click here to fix/improve performance of Windows." My guess is there was malicious software on one of the servers used by TOR, not on youtube. Anybody with thoughts on this, please let me know because it concerns me.

Comment: Are you sure the adware/malware wasn't already there before you started using Tor?

Comment: *My guess is there was malicious software on one of the servers used by TOR [...]* **--** Tor does not "use" any servers... if you are talking about relays, this is impossible (if you're surfing via http**s**) because all data is encrypted between you and your destination.